# Inconsistent results with queries of JSONFields in Django

Tags: django

I have a model like this:

```
class Task(models.Model):
   data = JSONField(encoder=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

and `data` is populated with either `{deleted: true}` or `{}`, but in the future might also have `{deleted: false}`. I'm trying to find how many Tasks are not deleted, but I get inconsistent results depending on what type of query I use.

If I use `Task.objects.exclude(data__deleted=True)`, I get 0, which is incorrect.

If I use `Task.objects.exclude(data__deleted='true')`, I get 58, which is incorrect.

If I use `Task.objects.filter(data__deleted__isnull=False)`, I get 29, which is correct but only happens to works since I don't have any `{deleted: false}` in the database currently.

Calculating manually like this:

```
count = 0
for task in Task.objects.all():
  if not task.data.get('deleted'):
    count += 1
```

also works because `count` is 29.

What is the proper query to use to filter the results correctly?

Comment: You appear to be really mixing up data types and truthyness comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Task.objects.filter(data__deleted=True)` you'll get the correct number for the deleted ones. The problem is you're excluding on a field that's not present in part of your instances. If all instances had the key `deleted` set to either `false` or `true` your exclude would work.

The reason is that if the key is missing, the object is skipped anyway.

So to get the instances that are not deleted, you need to combine those objects that don't have the key with those that have the key set to `false`:

```
Task.objects.filter(Q(data__deleted=False) | ~Q(data__has_key='deleted'))
```